# Can I use 2 manifests in one project

Tags: android

Can I make second manifest file in one project but without `android:icon` and `android:label`,so user will see only one app?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @stephanek. I just want to make simple lock screen app but I don't know how to disable home button I tried to add category:Home in my activity but  it didn't work and then I added category:LAUNCHER and it worked but always was like home screen when I need that it will be home screen only after user has pressed the button

Answer (score 0):

An app module will have one manifest file; you cannot have a second.

Libraries that contribute to the app may have their own manifest files. However, the contents of those manifests get merged with the app's manifest and other data sources (e.g., Gradle). In the end, your app still winds up with one manifest, with one `<manifest>` element and one `<application>` element.

In the future, you will get better results on Stack Overflow if you explain in your question what the real problem is (in this case, what you think having a second manifest will do for you). For example, if the reason you want two manifests is because you want two `<application>` elements, because you are trying to use two custom `Application` subclasses, that is not possible. You would need to arrange to have one `Application` subclass that provides all the functionality.

Comment: Hey,I've found your code in github, https://github.com/commonsguy/LockscreenLocker. How could you manage to block home button? I didn't understand

Comment: @Samuel: LockscreenLocker doesn't block the HOME button.

Comment: Do you know how to block it?If you do, can you please give me an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the user does not see the app in the launcher, they see the launcher activity. If you have more than one launcher activity they all appear in the launcher.

Comment: Launcher activity,you mean activity with category:launcher in intent filter?